# Determining a correct ML approach

Tags: classification

I've little idea about choosing a ML approach for the following problem. It is a classification problem and there are 2 classes that are `positive` and `negative`. There are about 100k samples and samples are structured like this:

```
Period = 1min   Pattern = M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>M3>B3
Period = 5min   Pattern = S1>M1>T1>B2>S2>M2>S3>T3>M3>B3
Period = 10min  Pattern = M1>T1>S1>M2>B2>S2>S3>T3>M3>B3
Period = 15min  Pattern = M1>T1>S1>B2>S3>M2>S2>T3>M3>B3
Period = 20min  Pattern = S1>M1>S3>T1>B2>M2>S2>T3>M3>B3
Period = 30min  Pattern = S1>S3>B2>M1>T1>S2>M2>T3>M3>B3
Period = 60min  Pattern = S1>B2>M1>T1>S2>M2>S3>T3>B3>M3
Period = 120min Pattern = S1>M1>T1>B2>S2>M2>T3>S3>M3>B3
```

This sample is classified as `negative`. A sample is composed of `8 periods`. Within each period there is a `pattern` such as `M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>M3>B3`. Each pattern has `10 elements` and their positions are changing along `samples and periods`. We need to come up with a solution that could tell which `period or lineup of elements` are responsible for classification.

Let's say we have `p1, p2, p3` positive examples and `n1, n2, n3` negative examples with `1min Periods` like this:

```
p1: M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>M3>B3
p2: M1>S1>T1>B2>S2>M2>S3>T3>M3>B3
p3: M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>M3>B3

n1: M1>S1>T1>B2>S2>M2>S3>T3>B3>M3
n2: M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>B3>M3
n3: M1>S1>T1>B2>M2>S2>S3>T3>B3>M3
```

It could be inferred that first 4 elements `M1,S1,T1, B2` are irrelevant for classification since they are all same across all samples. 5th and 6th elements are also irrelevant since they don't show same pattern along same class of samples. However, elements `B3, M3` is a solid positive since `M3>B3` for positive samples and `B3>M3` for negative samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to build proper features.

For each period and element, I would build a categorical feature. That is 80 categorical features. It looks like there aren't many possible values by feature, let's say there are 3 or 4 possible values for each feature, by doing one-hot encoding you would end up with 240-320 features.

Then you can do some kind of feature selection, like Lasso, and train your model with the selected features.